# What is a safe way to allow any windows user to encrypt a file but only a specific application decrypt it

Tags: password, certificate, .net

I've developed a service that reads text files from a location.  Some of the text files may contain sensitive information.  We would like to allow any user to run a standalone tool to encrypt the files such that only the service application can decrypt it.

I've created a MyServiceAccount.cer file and a passoword protected MyServiceAccount.pfx file with the public/private keys I need.  I have imported the MyServiceAccount.pfx into the personal store of MyServiceAccount by logging into Windows with that account. It seems awkward to have to login as a service account.

**1) Is there a way for an administrator to import a .cer or.pfx file into the another user's personal store?**

I've also created a stand alone tool that reads the MyServiceAccount.cer file to get the public key and encrypts one or more files with it. It seems awkward to have to leave the .cer file available for anyone to use, document where it is, hope no one moves or deletes it, etc.

**2) Is there an appropriate windows store where I should keep the MyServiceAccount.cer so that the standalone application can get the public key regardless of the which account the user running it is logged in as?**

Since the MyServiceAccount.pfx is stored in the personal store for the MySrviceAccount, I assume that the only account that can get the private key is that account.  I know an Administrator can login as that account so I should protect the private key so that a password is required. But..

**3) How can a service application access a key in the personal store that is password protected without embedding the password in the code?**

Thanks for any assistance in helping me understanding what my options are and what might be a best practice in this situation.

Comment: Why is it important for a certain app to decrypt? Encryption is done through known, and tested algorithms, which means that any code that uses those algorithms can decrypt. Isn't key management more important? The rest of the stated questions appear to be highly Windows admin specific, so I'm migrating to ServerFault.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, users' stores for private key are protected with a system known as [DPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API). Ultimately, the private keys get encrypted with a key derived (indirectly) from the user's password. Thus, no, even Administrator cannot push private keys into the private store of a user without typing the user's password at some point.

In your case, a better option might be to push the private key and certificate in the "LocalMachine" store. All users can read the certificates that are in that store, but cannot write into it. Moreover, by default, private key access is limited to administrators, but you can modify these access rights. Try using `mmc.exe`, then add the "Certificate" snap-in, selecting "local computer". This will allow you to import the PFX file specifically in the LocalMachine "My" store. Then, right-click on the certificate, do *not* choose "Properties"; instead, select "All tasks" then "Manage private key". This will lead you to the GUI for changing the private key access rights. Note: the "read" access right is sufficient to use the private key for cryptographic operations; the other rights are about deleting or overwriting the key.

If you still want to store things in the DPAPI for the service account, thus protected by the account's password, then you do not have to embed the password in the service code. Instead, you write the password in the system that launches the service -- for a "service" in the sense of `services.msc`, you have a GUI for that. Thus, you type the password when you install the service, but the rest is automatic.